# What is the difference between prophet package and fbprophet in Python?

Tags: python, time-series, facebook-prophet, prophet

I googled how to install the `fbprophet` package, but the top result is how to install `prophet`. What is the difference between the two packages? Are they the same?

Comment: I have googled, but didn't find much useful information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's by the same devs. Seems it was just a name change.

> Prophet is on PyPI, so you can use pip to install it. From v0.6
> onwards, Python 2 is no longer supported. As of v1.0, the package name
> on PyPI is "prophet"; prior to v1.0 it was "fbprophet".

https://pythonlang.dev/repo/facebook-prophet/